# Every Hilbert space is isometrically isomorphic with $\ell^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

> Let $H$ be a hilbert space and let $\{u_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in A}$ be a
>   orthornormal basis ($A$ is not supposed to be countable a priori).
>   Then there is an isometric isomorphism between $H$ and
>   $\ell^2(\mathcal{A})$ given by $x \mapsto \hat{x}$ with $\hat{x}_\alpha = \langle x,u_\alpha\rangle$.

*Proof:*

Linearity follows by linearity of scalar product: $(\widehat{ax + by})_\alpha = \langle ax + by,u_\alpha\rangle = a\langle x,u_\alpha\rangle + b\langle y,u_\alpha\rangle = a\hat{x}_\alpha + b\hat{y}_\alpha$

From Parseval we have $\|x\| = \sum_{\alpha \in A} |\langle x, u_\alpha\rangle| = \|\hat{x}\|_2$ and then the mapping is an isometry (and hence also injective).

To conclude we need to prove that this isometry is also surjective.

Let then $f$ be in $\ell^2(A)$. Then, by definition of $\ell^2$, $\sum_{\alpha \in A} |f_\alpha|^2 < \infty$, this implies that $|\{\alpha : f_\alpha \not = 0 \}| \le |\mathbb{N}|$ and thus also the sum $\sum_{\alpha \in A} f_\alpha u_\alpha$ has countable many nonzero terms. Then, by Pythagorean theorem (using continuity of inner product) $\|\sum f_\alpha u_\alpha \|^2 = \sum_{\alpha \in A} |f_\alpha|^2 < \infty$ so this series is absolutely convergent and then $z = \sum_{\alpha \in A} f_\alpha u_\alpha$ exists. Clearly $\hat{z} = f$ 
$\square$

**Q1: Is this proof correct?**

---

This proof is worked out from Folland's Real Analysis book. In the book though, Prof. Folland writes:

> If $f \in \ell^2(A)$ then $\sum_{\alpha \in A} |f_\alpha|^2 < \infty$
>   so the Pythagorean theorem shows that partial sums of the series
>   $\sum_{\alpha \in A} f_\alpha u_\alpha$ (of which only countable many
>   terms are nonzero) are Cauchy.

I know the definitions but I don't get why Prof. Folland says that Pythagorean theorem asserts that partial sums are Cauchy. I think Pythagorean theorem in this case give us absolute convergence of the sum, not just the fact partial sums are Cauchy. In this case the space is complete so there is no real distinction between Cauchy and convergence but I care about logical order of the proof.

**Q2: Why Pythagorean theorem asserts only Cauchy property of partial sums and not absolute convergence as I said?**

Thanks in advance

---

<sub>**Note:** Uncountable sums of non negative terms are defined like this:
$$ \sum_{\alpha \in A} g(\alpha) := \sup \left\{ \sum_{\alpha \in F} g(\alpha) : F \subset A, \ F \ \text{finite} \right\}$$
with $g: A \to [0,\infty)$</sub>

Comment: what is $l^2(A)$ when $A$ is not countable ?

Comment: $\ell^2(A) = \{f : A \to \mathbb{C} : \sum_{\alpha \in A} |f_\alpha|^2 < \infty\}$ and the sum is intended in the sense of sup

Comment: shouldn't the main argument of your proof be that even in a non-separable Hilbert space every element is a countable sum of non-zero orthogonal vectors  $f = \sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n \psi(a_n)$ where $\psi(a)$ is the orthonormal uncountable basis, or at least that they are dense in the Hilbert space ? (or equivalently that $||\sum_{a \in E} c(a) \psi(a)||$ (defined with your $\sup$) cannot be finite if $E$ is a non countable subset of $A$ and $c(a)$ is never $0$ ?)

Comment: But this is used in some sense in the proof of Folland. If $f \in \ell^2(A)$ the convergence of the sum implies that $f_\alpha \not = 0$ only in a countable subset of $A$. The $\sum f_\alpha u_\alpha$ is indeed a countable sum and then Pythagorean theorem applies.

Comment: so I don't understand your problem once this is proved, replace every $\sum_{a \in A}$ by $\sum_{n=1}^\infty$ since we know we can ?

Comment: If you like measures better, think of $\ell^2(\Lambda)$ as $L^2_{\mu}(\Lambda)$ where $\mu$ is counting measuree on $\Lambda$. Then the sums become integrals. These are equivalent.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments. I edited question in order to clean up and add a question

Comment: Maybe Q2 depends on what you mean by "the Pythagorean theorem".  But for instance, in an incomplete inner product space, it's entirely possible that a series of the form $\sum_{\alpha} f_\alpha u_\alpha$, where $\sum_\alpha |f_\alpha|^2 < \infty$ and $u_\alpha$ are orthonormal, fails to converge.

Comment: @user1952009. In a non-separable Hilbert space every vector is equal to the sum of its projections onto an orthonormal basis, but only countably many of these projections are non-zero. Such vectors are not merely dense, they are the whole space.

Comment: @ user254665 : what I wrote above is that (if possible) this should be the first thing to be proved about non-separable Hilbert spaces. after it has been proved, everything is easier as all these $\sum_{a \in A} f(a) = \sup \{ \sum_{a \in F} f(a) \  | \  F \subset A \}$ can be replaced by simple series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(a_n)$

Answer (score 4):

If $\mathcal{H}$ is a Hilbert space and $\{ e_{\alpha} \}_{\alpha\in\Lambda}$ is an orthonormal subset on $\mathcal{H}$, then
$$
     x=\left(x-\sum_{n=1}^{N}(x,e_{\alpha_n})e_{\alpha_n}\right)+\sum_{n=1}^{N}(x,e_{\alpha_n})e_{\alpha_n} \;\;\; (\dagger)
$$
is an orthogonal decomposition. Therefore,
\begin{align}
          \|x\|^2&=\|x-\sum_{n=1}^{N}(x,e_{\alpha_n})e_{\alpha_n}\|^2+\|\sum_{n=1}^{N}(x,e_{\alpha_n})e_{\alpha_n}\|^2 \\
        &\ge \|\sum_{n=1}^{N}(x,e_{\alpha_n})e_{\alpha_n}\|^2 \\
        &= \sum_{n=1}^{N}|(x,e_{\alpha_n})|^2
\end{align}
Therefore, for any $\epsilon > 0$, the following set is finite:
$$
             \Lambda_{x,\epsilon}=\{ \alpha \in \Lambda : |(x,e_{\alpha})| \ge \epsilon \}
$$
Therefore, the following set is empty, finite, or countable infinite.
$$
           \{ \alpha\in \Lambda : (x,e_{\alpha}) \ne 0 \} = \bigcup_{N=1}^{\infty}\Lambda_{x,1/N}.
$$
Let $x\in\mathcal{H}$, and let $\{\alpha_n\}$ be an enumeration of the $\alpha\in\Lambda$ for which $(x,e_{\alpha})\ne 0$. The only interesting case is where this set of indices is countably infinite. In that case, the original orthogonal decomposition $(\dagger)$ gives
$$
         \|x\|^2=\|x-\sum_{n=1}^{N}(x,e_{\alpha_n})e_{\alpha_n}\|^2+\sum_{n=1}^{N}|(x,e_{\alpha_n})|^2.
$$
Therefore $\|x\|^2=\lim_{N}\sum_{n=1}^{N}|(x,e_{\alpha_n})|^2$ iff
$$
            \lim_{N}\|x-\sum_{n=1}^{N}(x,e_{\alpha_n})e_{\alpha_n}\|=0.
$$
So, Parseval's equality holds for some $x$ with respect to $\{ e_{\alpha} \}_{\alpha\in\Lambda}$ iff $\lim_{N}\sum_{n=1}^{N}(x,e_{\alpha_n})e_{\alpha_n}=x$ converges in the norm of $\mathcal{H}$. And, in that case, any ordering for the sum will give the same limit because the Parseval equality involves an absolutely convergent series of positive numbers and, hence, may be ordered in any way. This is what is meant by the unordered sum converging.