# Is $L^2(\mathbb R)$ isometrically isomorphic with $\ell^2(\mathbb Z)?$

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, operator-theory, harmonic-analysis

Is $L^2(\mathbb R)$ isometrically isomorphic with $\ell^2(\mathbb Z)?$

My thoughts:
We can define an operator $\mathcal L:L^2(\mathbb R)\rightarrow \ell^2(\mathbb Z)$ : $\mathcal Lf=\{\hat f(ξ)\}_{ξ\in \mathbb Z}$ 
(obviously $\mathcal L$ is linear & $1-1$ by uniqueness) and  by the Parseval identity we have that $\lVert f\rVert_{L^2(\mathbb R)}^2=\lVert \hat f\rVert_{\ell^2(\mathbb Z)}^2$ Hence we have an isometry.
is that enough?
Also, can we claim that $:L^2(\mathbb R)≅ \ell^2(\mathbb Z)?$ 
Thanks you.
EDIT: how about $L^2([a,b])?$

Comment: @LeechLattice Actually, $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ is complete. For any measure space $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ and for any $p\in [1,\infty]$ the space $L^p(X)$ is a Banach space. Read the comments and answers to the question in your link very carefully.

Comment: Rather than trying to construct individual isometries by hand, you should try to prove that any two infinite dimensional separable Hilbert spaces are isometric. You can do this by showing that any infinite dimensional separable Hilbert space $H$ is isometric to $\mathbb \ell^2(\mathbb N)$. To do this, let $(h_i)_{i=1}^\infty$ be a complete orthonormal system for $H$ (prove that such a thing exists!), and let $(e_i)_{i=1}^\infty$ be one for $\ell^2(\mathbb N)$, and consider the continuous linear map that sends $h_i$ to $e_i$ for each $i$.

Comment: You are right, i've already proved it,but $L^2$ is a space with functions and $\ell ^2$ a space of sequences, can we claim that they are isomorphic? ,thank you

Comment: @John Mars Why should it matter how we call the elements? Obviously, all Hilbert spaces are different from each other, but they still might be isomorphic.

Comment: Thank you, now its clear.

Comment: @LeechLattice : $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ is the space of complex (or real) square-integrable, Lebesgue measurable functions on $\mathbb{R}$ grouped by the equivalence relation of being equal a.e. according to Lebesgue measure. $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ is complete. It is a Hilbert space.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Recall that $L^2(\Bbb R)$ is a separable Hilbert space and hence has a countable Orthonormal Basis say $\{e_n\}_{n \in \Bbb Z}$. This implies that $L^2(\Bbb R)$ is isometrically isomorphic to $\ell^2(\Bbb Z)$, by the linear map $f \mapsto \{\langle f,e_n\rangle\}_{n \in \Bbb Z}$  . For more clarity and details of the argument [check here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1651740/every-hilbert-space-is-isometrically-isomorphic-with-ell2). As a matter of fact, there exists only one separable infinite-dimensional Hilbert space upto isometric isomorphism, namely $\ell^2(\Bbb Z)$

Comment: should be "only one separable INFINITEDIMENSIONAL Hilbert space ...", obviously $l^2(\{1,...,n\})$ is separable.

Comment: @DominikKutek Do we really bother about finite dimensional spaces while doing Analysis?

Comment: @Brozovic I know that , but 2 is a space with functions and ℓ2 a space with sequences, can we claim that theorem in this case?
Thank you.

Comment: @JohnMars I don't see why you can't. All I am concerned is with that both are separable Hilbert spaces hence both have countable Orthonormal bases.

Comment: @Brozovic: *Do we really bother about finite dimensional spaces while doing Analysis?* **Yes, we do.**

Answer (score 5):

Another explicit example of an orthonormal basis for $L^2(\mathbb R)$ is $(e^{2\pi i m x} I_{n \le x < n+1})_{(m,n) \in \mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z}$.  And since $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ is in one to one correspondence with $\mathbb Z$, this gives another isometry from $L^2(\mathbb R)$ to $\ell^2(\mathbb Z)$.

Answer (score 4):

The normalized Hermite functions form an orthonormal basis of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. These are
$$
     H_n(x)=(-1)^n(2^n n!\sqrt{\pi})^{-1/2}e^{x^2/2}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}e^{-x^2},\;\;\; n=0,1,2,3,\cdots.
$$
$\{ H_n \}$ is a countable orthonormal basis of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. It is not hard to use this in order to map $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ unitarily onto $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$.